# Variational AutoEncoder- Keras- logits and labels must have the same shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I'm walking through this example on Keras  https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/

However, I'm trying to replicate this with a 200-by-200 dimension image. The specific error I'm receiving is:

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 8, 8, 1) vs (None, 200, 200, 3))
```

This is my encoder with a modified keras.Input(shape=(200, 200, 3))

```
latent_dim = 2

encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(200, 200, 3))
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(encoder_inputs)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(x)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(x)
z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(x)
z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_var])
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name="encoder")
encoder.summary()
```

```
Model: "encoder"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_17 (InputLayer)           [(None, 200, 200, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               (None, 100, 100, 32) 896         input_17[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 50, 50, 64)   18496       conv2d_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_4 (Flatten)             (None, 160000)       0           conv2d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)                (None, 16)           2560016     flatten_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
z_mean (Dense)                  (None, 2)            34          dense_16[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
z_log_var (Dense)               (None, 2)            34          dense_16[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sampling_3 (Sampling)           (None, 2)            0           z_mean[0][0]                     
                                                                 z_log_var[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 2,579,476
Trainable params: 2,579,476
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I believe the error lies within my decoder, which I tried to modify the layers.Dense by a factor of 200.

```
latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
x = layers.Dense(2 * 2 * 50, activation="relu")(latent_inputs)
x = layers.Reshape((2, 2, 50))(x) ##changed this
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
decoder_outputs = layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation="sigmoid", padding="same")(x)
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name="decoder")
decoder.summary()
```

```
Model: "decoder"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_18 (InputLayer)        [(None, 2)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 200)               600       
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_12 (Reshape)         (None, 2, 2, 50)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_13 (Conv2DT (None, 4, 4, 64)          28864     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_14 (Conv2DT (None, 8, 8, 32)          18464     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_15 (Conv2DT (None, 8, 8, 1)           289       
=================================================================
Total params: 48,217
Trainable params: 48,217
Non-trainable params: 0
```

My image size for pic1 is:

```
(312, 465)
```

I then run this, and hit the error:

```
pic_1 = np.expand_dims(pic1, 0).astype("float32") / 255 

pic_1 = pic_1[:,-201:-1, 0:200] #Trim the picture to fit the input 200-by-200 dimensions

vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
vae.fit(pic_1, epochs=30, batch_size=128)
```

Which is were I receive this error:

```
        raise ValueError("logits and labels must have the same shape (%s vs %s)" %

    ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 8, 8, 1) vs (None, 200, 200, 3))
```

Like I said, I think there is something wrong with my output shape of the decoder, as it doesn't match the input shape of the encoder? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to make sure that the latent representation gets upscaled to `( 200 , 200 , 3 )` and not `( 8 , 8 , 3 )`. You can do this by adding additional `Conv2DTranspose` layers.

Comment: How can I add the correct number of layers to equal 200, 200, 3? For example I added

x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)

Comment: conv2d_transpose_269 (Conv2D (None, 10, 10, 64)        4672      
conv2d_transpose_270 (Conv2D (None, 20, 20, 64)        36928     
conv2d_transpose_271 (Conv2D (None, 40, 40, 64)        36928     
conv2d_transpose_272 (Conv2D (None, 80, 80, 32)        18464     
conv2d_transpose_273 (Conv2D (None, 160, 160, 32)      9248      
conv2d_transpose_274 (Conv2D (None, 320, 320, 16)      4624      
conv2d_transpose_275 (Conv2D (None, 320, 320, 3)       435

Answer (score 0):

The decoder does not need to be exactly equal to the encoder (same layers and length) but needs that the input has the same shape as output. Basically, you can change the layers of the decoder, but the final layer shape must be (200,200,3). The easy way to do that is by mirroring the decoder based on the encoder. Follow an example:

```
latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
x = layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(latent_inputs)
x = layers.Dense(50 * 50 * 64, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Reshape((50, 50, 64))(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
decoder_outputs = layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, 3, activation="sigmoid", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name="decoder")
decoder.summary()
```

Other example with the decoder different from encoder, but always with the output shape (200,200,3) is:

```
latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
x = layers.Dense(8, activation="relu")(latent_inputs)
x = layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Dense(50 * 50 * 64, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Reshape((50, 50, 64))(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=1, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=1, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
decoder_outputs = layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, 3, activation="sigmoid", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, decoder_outputs, name="decoder")
decoder.summary()
```